# How to Fill Colour with Animation in UIImage particular portion?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, flood-fill

I have flood fill Image functionality in my app and it's working fine, but now I want to fill Colour on specific portion of Image with Animation.

I have used below library ho achive flood fill.

[Github link](https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill)

Here I am sharing reference video link so anyone can get idea that which and where animation I want.

**Reference Video link**:- [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a2cMl2QoyrcgC5_fYXE8Z5B74k0sXmf4/view)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* edit that code and update the image every *n* iterations... but, that might make it too slow, and might not give you the desired effect anyway.

Another option, which may or may not suit your needs, would be to animate a mask to "reveal" the newly-color-filled image.

Could look something like this:

[image]

If the oval animation doesn't suffice, you could play around with a shape mask such as this:

[image]

animating its scale from tiny to large enough to cover the view.

---

**Edit**

Here's a quick example of animating a shape mask (put an image named "sample" in your assets):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let imgView = UIImageView()

    // the image view will be completely clear to begin with
    //  so we need a view to show where to tap
    let tapView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "sample") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!")
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        tapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tapView)
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(imgView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // center the image view
            imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            // let's give it a width of 240
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            // use original image aspect ratio
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: img.size.height / img.size.width),
            
            // "tap view" same frame as the image view
            tapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.topAnchor),
            tapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.leadingAnchor),
            tapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.trailingAnchor),
            tapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.bottomAnchor),

        ])

        // so we can see the tap view frame
        tapView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        imgView.image = img
        
        // Image View starts with empty mask (so it is completely clear)
        imgView.layer.mask = CALayer()

        // tap gesture recognizer
        let tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)))
        tapView.addGestureRecognizer(tg)
        
    }
    
    @objc func gotTap(_ gr: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // run the animation, using the tap point as the oval center
        animMask(imgView, pt: gr.location(in: tapView))
    }
    
    func animMask(_ v: UIView, pt: CGPoint) {

        // final oval mask has to cover the entire view
        let largeOvalRadius: CGFloat = sqrt((v.bounds.width * v.bounds.width) + (v.bounds.height * v.bounds.height))
        
        // small oval rect is 4x1 points, centered on the tapped point
        let smallOvalRect: CGRect = .init(x: pt.x - 2.0, y: pt.y, width: 4.0, height: 1.0)
        
        // large oval rect is small oval rect inset by the calculated radius
        let largeOvalRect: CGRect = smallOvalRect.insetBy(dx: -largeOvalRadius, dy: -largeOvalRadius)
        
        // shape layer to use as the layer mask
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        // can be any solid color
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        
        // set initial path to oval that covers entire view
        let pth = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: largeOvalRect).cgPath
        shape.path = pth
        shape.frame = v.bounds
        v.layer.mask = shape
        
        // animate the path on the mask layer
        let morphAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        // from very small oval
        morphAnimation.fromValue = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: smallOvalRect).cgPath
        // to very large oval
        morphAnimation.toValue = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: largeOvalRect).cgPath
        // 3/4 second animation (for example)
        morphAnimation.duration = 0.75
        // we don't want any easing
        morphAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .linear)
        
        // start the animation
        shape.add(morphAnimation, forKey: nil)
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]

If you want to use that with your "flood fill" ...

First, I would edit that flood fill code (or find another example).

Instead of encapsulating it in a subclassed `UIImageView`, have it:

- accept an image, color and point
- return the new image

Then, overlay one image view on top of another, where the "top" image view begins with an empty mask (so it's completely clear). On tap:

- get a flood-filled image based on the "bottom" image
- set that as the `.image` of the "top" image view
- run a "reveal" mask animation on the "top" image view
- replace the `.image` of the "bottom" image view with the new image
- reset the empty mask on the "top" image view

Lather, rinse, repeat.

You could also optimize the animation by having the flood-fill code also return the changed bounds, and then make the "end" mask only as large as needed to cover the changed area.

Example project here: https://github.com/DonMag/FloodAnim

Comment: is there any code for masking, which you show in first image?

Comment: Thanks for help, but oval effect apply on whole image instead of particular portion. any solutions of that @DonMag

Comment: @Berlin - not really sure what you mean... is the effect from the first animated image   in my answer acceptable?

Comment: Your answer is right and relatable but the issue is masking effect apply on whole image. and my requirement is only masking need to apply on particular portion where colour is fill. like same as you add first gif in your answer. @DonMag

Comment: @Berlin - that's exactly what I outlined with the bullet points. I posted an example project here: https://github.com/DonMag/FloodAnim

Comment: Thanks for help, but if I changed Image in your example project. it won't work.

Comment: @Berlin - I'm happy to try and help you, but *"it won't work"* doesn't give me much information... https://imgur.com/a/jE3wrm5

Comment: Thanks @DonMag, for the support. but it can't work for me